# Xamarin.Forms: Comparing ImageSource

Tags: xamarin, comparison, xamarin.forms, imagesource

If `cachePath` would be a string I could do this

```
if(value.Equals(this.cachePath, StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

Now `cachePath` is of type [`ImageSource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource/). How can I compare if `value` is the same as `cachePath`? Currently I'm doing this

```
if(this.cachePath == value)
```

Is this the only way? Or how can `Equals()` be used for this?

Comment: Because `ImageSource` is a `Reference Type` comparing two `ImageSources` will compare the References. NOT the actual data. because `String` is a `Value Type` the comparing WILL compare the actual string and not the reference. You want to convert to a `Byte[]` and compare the two byte arrays to get a true comparison

Comment: I think that would be very time consuming to read a whole picture into a `byte[]`. Isn't there a way to know if the references are pointing to the same resource?

Comment: if the references are the same. I.e. `this.cachePath` is the same object as `value`. i.e. `this.cachePath = value` then this is checking the references. BUT if `cachePath` is a copy of the image `value` then EVENTHO the images ARE the same image, because they are not pointing to the same object `cachePath == Value` would return `false`

Comment: OK, after the rules of pass-by-reference/pass-by-value. You could summarize your comments into an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this comes down to the age old "*Pass by reference*" / "*Pass by Value*" discussion.

Because `ImageSource` is a **Reference Type** comparing two `ImageSources` will compare the References. **NOT** the actual data.

because `String` is a **Value Type** the comparison **WILL** compare the actual string and not the reference.

For a true comparison of your `ImageSource` want to convert to a `Byte[]` and compare the two byte arrays as these will be **Value types**

**With reference to your question:**

If `this.cachePath` is the same **object** as `value`. i.e:

```
this.cachePath = value
this.cachePath == value
//Returns true
```

**BUT** if `cachePath` is a copy of the image `value` then **EVENTHO** the images **ARE** the same, because their references are not pointing to the same object

```
this.cachePath = new ImageSource();
this.value = new ImageSource(cachePath.Source);
this.cachePath == Value 
// Returns False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution for this problem is to create your own custom image object like this:

```
public class MyImage : Image
{
   public string CompareName { get; set; }
}
```

So, MyImage class will have every property of its base Image class, plus, it will have a CompareName property. Whenever you set the ImageSource of the object, you can give it a name for future comparing operations. I think this will be a better solution than comparing the whole image source file.